# как сменить navbar-toggle на navbar-toggle-open

Tags: bootstrap

Здраствуйте! Подскажите пожалуста, как можна сделать чтоб при нажатии на кнопку navbar-toggle, ета кнопочка менялась на крестик navbar-toggle-open.?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать готовый плагин, коих тьма уже развилась, на любой вкус. А можно в бургере скрыть линию по середине, а верхнюю и нижнюю повернуть под углом.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
   top: 1px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
   top: 2px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
   position: relative;
   transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
   top: 6px;
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
   background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggle.active .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
   top: -6px;
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Бургер с анимацией</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Кнопка домой</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```